# Scheduling algorithm in Racket (ASL)

Tags: racket, recursive-backtracking, mutual-recursion

I need to blend aspects of an arbitrary arity tree with generative recursion and backtracking in order to come up with a simple valid schedule.

So far I have two structures, one that identifies the individual with her availability slots and maximum number of slots that she can work: `(define-struct ta [name max avail])` and an assignment structure as an ordered pair: `(define-struct assignment [ta slot])` where slot is simply a natural number. So for instance I have the following unit tests with the following dummies:

```
(define SOBA (make-ta "Soba" 2 (list 1 3)))
(define UDON (make-ta "Udon" 1 (list 3 4)))
(define RAMEN (make-ta "Ramen" 1 (list 2)))

(define NOODLE-TAs (list SOBA UDON RAMEN))
```

```
(check-expect (schedule-tas empty empty) empty)
(check-expect (schedule-tas empty (list 1 2)) false)
(check-expect (schedule-tas (list SOBA) empty) empty) 
(check-expect (schedule-tas NOODLE-TAs (list 1 2 3 4)) 
              (list
               (make-assignment UDON 4)
               (make-assignment SOBA 3)
               (make-assignment RAMEN 2)
               (make-assignment SOBA 1)))
```

So my main function right now looks like this:

```
;; (listof TA) (listof Slot) -> Schedule or false
;; produces valid schedule given TAs and Slots; false if impossible;
;; Schedule is (listof Assignment), Assigment is (make-assignment TA Slot)
(define (schedule-tas tas slots)
  (local [(define (fn-for-tas tas)
            (cond [(empty? slots) empty]
                  [(and (empty? tas)(cons? slots)) #f]                    ;From two 'One-Of' type analysis
                  [else
                   (if (all-assigned? (next-assignments tas slots) slots) ;Generative-recursion through 'next-assignments'   
                       (next-assignments tas slots)                       ;I know about the duplication of the computation here.
                       (fn-for-loa (next-assignments tas slots)))]))      ;just waiting to have a working version before I make it less readable

          (define (fn-for-loa loa)
            (cond [(empty? loa) #f]
                  [else
                   (local [(define try (fn-for-tas (first loa)))]
                     (if (not (false? try))
                         try
                         (fn-for-loa (rest loa))))]))]
    (fn-for-tas tas)))
```

So to produce the data through generative recursion I wished for `(next-assignments tas slots)` as a composition of what I need: make all assignments and filter by availabity and maximum number of workable slots:

```
;; (listof TA) (listof Slot) -> (listof Assignment)
;; creates next list of possible valid assignments
(define (next-assignments tas slots)
  (filter-by-max (filter-by-availability (all-assignments tas slots))))
```

```
(define (all-assignments tas slots)
  (local [(define (assign-ta ta)
            (map (λ (s) (make-assignment ta s)) slots))

          (define (all-assignments tas)
            (cond [(empty? tas) empty]
                  [else
                   (append (assign-ta (first tas))
                           (all-assignments (rest tas)))]))]
    (all-assignments tas)))
```

However I am not convinced that this is what I need since it rather creating the whole searchable space in one go instead of the branch-and-prune strategy that I need to implement. Anyways, the rest of the auxiliary functions are here, for completeness:

```
(define (filter-by-availability loa)
  (cond [(empty? loa) empty]
        [else
         (if (member? (assignment-slot (first loa))
                      (ta-avail (assignment-ta (first loa))))
             (cons (first loa) (filter-by-availability (rest loa)))    
             (filter-by-availability (rest loa)))]))

(define (filter-by-max loa)
  (cond [(empty? loa) empty]
        [else
         (if (> (length loa) (ta-max (assignment-ta (first loa))))
             (filter-by-max (rest loa))
             loa)]))
```

I am also not very happy with these filtering functions as they seem too 'dumb' somehow; they just drop whichever ta they happen to find in order to satisfy the conditions.

And finally, I have the base case of the generative recursion:

```
(define (all-assigned? loa slots)
  (= (length loa)
     (length slots)))
```

which is somehow the 'dumbest' one of all, I think. Anyways, as you can see I am not happy with my code. But the main problem that I see with it is, again, that I don't think I am generating a bone-fide tree. So if you could just let know how to do that I would be immensely grateful!

N.B. This is for a course I am taking but I think you can tell that I have really tried. Please help!

Comment: Can someone at least tell me what's wrong with the way that I've posted the question? That is, given that I have not received any help. Thank you.

Comment: You question is simultaneously too specific and too general for people to easily answer. Its too specific because you essentially put up a large block of code that the reader must read to understand what you are asking. Its too general because your question seems to be 'I don't like this, how do I do it better?". Which can be a bit subjective. Does that make any sense?

Comment: As a side note, it does look like you certainly have tried. Which is certainly a very good start. :)

Comment: True, you are right. Let me see how to compose it better.